# Google CloudFunctions Gen2 terraform policy doesn't create a resource

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create a cloud function gen2 using terraform, and allow allUsers to access it. It's a webhook for another platform and it must be public.

```
resource "google_cloudfunctions2_function_iam_member" "v2invoker" {
  depends_on = [google_cloudfunctions2_function.default]

  project        = google_cloudfunctions2_function.default.project
  cloud_function = google_cloudfunctions2_function.default.name
  location       = google_cloudfunctions2_function.default.location

  role   = "roles/cloudfunctions.invoker"
  member = "allUsers"
}
```

This code successfully applies, but function is yet not available. I used gcloud official recommendation:

```
gcloud functions add-invoker-policy-binding my_function_name \
      --region="europe-west1" \
      --member="allUsers"
```

and it worked! I tried to find where I can see all these policy bindings but "permissions" page doesn't show any of such. How can I validate that my binding created?

---

Complete HCL:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = ">= 4.34.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "google" {
  project = "my-project-123456"
  region  = "europe-west1"
}

resource "random_id" "default" {
  byte_length = 8
}

resource "google_storage_bucket" "default" {
  name                        = "${random_id.default.hex}-gcf-source" # Every bucket name must be globally unique
  location                    = "EUROPE-WEST1"
  uniform_bucket_level_access = true
}

data "archive_file" "default" {
  type        = "zip"
  output_path = "/tmp/function-source.zip"
  source_dir  = "src/"
}

resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "object" {
  name   = "function-source.zip"
  bucket = google_storage_bucket.default.name
  source = data.archive_file.default.output_path # Add path to the zipped function source code
}

resource "google_cloudfunctions2_function" "default" {
  name        = "my-bot"
  description = "my function bot"
  location    = "europe-west1"
  build_config {
    runtime     = "python311"
    entry_point = "handle" # Set the entry point
    source {
      storage_source {
        bucket = google_storage_bucket.default.name
        object = google_storage_bucket_object.object.name
      }
    }
  }

  service_config {
    max_instance_count    = 1
    available_memory      = "256M"
    timeout_seconds       = 60
    ingress_settings      = "ALLOW_ALL"
    environment_variables = {
      BOT_TOKEN = file("${path.module}/bot_token.txt")
    }
  }
}


resource "google_cloudfunctions2_function_iam_member" "v2invoker" {
  depends_on = [google_cloudfunctions2_function.default]

  project        = google_cloudfunctions2_function.default.project
  cloud_function = google_cloudfunctions2_function.default.name
  location       = google_cloudfunctions2_function.default.location

  role   = "roles/cloudfunctions.invoker"
  member = "allUsers"
}


output "function_uri" {
  value = google_cloudfunctions2_function.default.service_config[0].uri
}
```

Comment: Show the entire HCL for the function resources. What is the provider version? Are you also using an `_iam_policy` or `_iam_binding`?

Comment: Added HCL, provider 4.34. No, I'm not using policy nor binding

Comment: What do the Cloud Functions logs show?

Comment: I am guessing, but I think you have a `depends_on` condition. The function must be deployed before the policy binding can be modified.

Comment: Hey John, I'm a bit confused, but I do have this condition. Do you think it must be there, or I have to remove it? logs are flooded with 403 errors, nothing else meaningful

Comment: Does this help? https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/depends_on I am **guessing** that your IAM code is trying to set permissions before the resource is ready.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I have depends on parameter set to my function in `iam` code

Comment: Double-check the IAM policy binding manually using the gcloud command-line tool. This will help verify if the policy binding was successfully created, even if it's not immediately visible in the Google Cloud Console.<br>

Comment: @Chanpols what would be an example command to receive such policy? I think this would help me to make a proper bug request to terraform guys